# Disable Button on CardView android

Tags: java, android, jodatime, android-cardview

I am having trouble in setting the `Button` to invisible on a `CardView` after particular time

**What i am trying to achieve:**
I have a `CardView` with a `Button`. 
When user places an order, order date & time is stored in MySQL server DB. I get this time from server and add 10 mins delay to it.

Now this time is considered to make the `Button` invisble/gone in `CardView`.

**What am i using:**
    For time, am using Joda Time & 
    whatever code below is inside the `onBindViewHolder()` of `Recyclerview`

**What i have tried so far:**
I get the time from server

```
String orderDate = cOrder.getOrderDate(); // 2016-08-18 00:02:32
```

Then convert the time to `Date` format

```
DateTimeFormatter dateTimeFormatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
        DateTime dt = dateTimeFormatter.parseDateTime(orderDate);
```

I add 10 minutes to the time using the below, to set the delay

```
 DateTime delay = dt.plusMinutes(10);
```

Now i set the delay time on the `Button` using `postDelayed()`

```
 holder.btnCancel.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    holder.btnCancel.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            }, delay.getMillis());
```

Now when i run the app, the button on the `CardView` should have disappeared as *orderDate was (18th Aug - Two days before current).*

I tried using regular Java time as well instead of JODA but no luck.

I am unable to figure out what the issue is. Requesting your guidance.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#postDelayed(java.lang.Runnable,%20long)) of `postDelayed()`:

> `delayMillis` `long`: The delay (in milliseconds) until the `Runnable` will
>   be executed.

Let's add 10 minutes to `2016-08-18 00:02:32` and convert it to milliseconds (from the epoch). That equals to something like `1471471952000`.

You're passing this value to `postDelayed()` as the delay, effectively telling the `Handler` to execute this `Runnable` after `1471471952000` milliseconds, which is roughly equals to 47 years.

That does not really make sense.

To hide your `Button` if the given `Date` is before the current `Date`, you could do something like this:

```
String orderDateString = cOrder.getOrderDate();
try {
    Date now = new Date();
    Date orderDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss",
            Locale.getDefault()).parse(orderDateString);

    if(orderDate.before(now)) {
        holder.btnCancel.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
} catch (ParseException pe) {
    pe.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Thanks much for this. I was able to fix the issue with your help. THanks again :)

Answer (score 1):

@user13 answer is good explain of how `postDelayed()` works, so you should try this code:

```
holder.btnCancel.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                holder.btnCancel.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        }, (10 * 60 * 1000)); // 10 min * 50 sec * 1000 ms
                              // or delay.getMillis() - dt.getMillis()
```

Comment: I modified my code based on @user13 suggestion to achieve the desired results. Thank you so much :)